# Ошибка в debug у Yii

Tags: yii, netbeans

```
public function actionLogin()
{
        $model=new LoginForm;

        // collect user input data
        if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
        {
```

- Если запускать без дебага, то все работает
- Если поставить точку останова на условие, то первая строчка проходит хорошо
- Если ставить точку останова на создание модели, то при шаге дебага возникает FatalError

Вот сама ошибка:

> CException: Не определено свойство "CWebApplication.pass". in E:\xampp\htdocs\yii\base\CComponent.php on line 130

Раньше работало, сегодня не пойму что случилось. Любой рендер, редирект и подгрузка модуля вызывает вот эту ошибку (с разными именами файлами) но с одним расширением .pass . Но опять же, если без дебага, то все работает так как должно.

Использую NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528)

Перезагрузка апача и среды не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в watched expressions ничего не стоит?

Comment: Спасибо ))) Оказывается стояло, я даже не обратил внимание )